# Qt - invoke slot only when both signals are emitted

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have 3 processes: `A`, `B` and `Final`. `Final` depends on both `A` and `B` and can/must only be updated when both `A` and `B` are updated. There is a signal `dataChanged` that updates both `A` and `B` (and so `Final` as well). Slots `update_A` and `update_B` are also invoked by other signals.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent),
    pA(false),
    pB(false)
{
...
connect(this, &MainWindow::xChanged, this, &MainWindow::update_A);
connect(this, &MainWindow::yChanged, this, &MainWindow::update_B);
connect(myObj, &MyClass::dataChanged, this, &MainWindow::update_A);
connect(myObj, &MyClass::dataChanged, this, &MainWindow::update_B);
connect(this, &MainWindow::a_Updated, this, &MainWindow::update_final);
connect(this, &MainWindow::b_Updated, this, &MainWindow::update_final);
...
}

void MainWindow::update_A() {
  if (!this.pA) {
    // do something 
  }
  this.pA = true;
  emit a_Updated;
}

void MainWindow::update_B() {
  if (!this.pB) {
    // do something 
  }
  this.pB = true;
  emit b_Updated;
}

void MainWindow::update_final() {
  if (this.pA && this.pB) {
    // do something
    this.pA = false;
    this.pB = false;
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to combine the signals with the AND operator to get rid off using `pA` and `pB`? Or did I use signals and slots in a wrong way?

EDIT: Sorry that I forgot to mention: `update_A` and `update_B` are also invoked by other signals, so I have to keep them as separated slots. And I updated the question and code above.

Comment: are update_A and update_B blocking? are all objects in one thread? because slots are called in the order they were connected, so update_B will always be called once update_A has finished. if you connect the final slot to dataChanged after the 2 other connects, the slot will be called once update_B has finished

Comment: why not use a single slot which invokes these functions (which in turn can return `bool` to check the state) and only call the `Finish` if all functions succeed?

Comment: since the slots are connected to other signals as well, i can't combine them. `dataChanged` is just one signal that invokes both. There are signals that invoke just one of the slots, but once both slots are invoked, the `update_final` must be called as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no supplied signal combination operators in Qt.  You'll need to implement your own, as you have done, or like:

```
void MainWindow::update_A() {
  if (!pA) {
    // do something 
  }
  pA = true;
  if (pA && pB)
      emit ab_Updated();
}
```

If you use this pattern frequently, it may be worthwhile to define an object class with the sole responsibility of logical operations on signal sequences.  To be complete, you would want 'A before B' and 'A after B' operators too.

Comment: can you please give me an example of such class?

Comment: No, I won't give an example - you have the logic, and it's just a matter of separating out the relevant code into its own class.  It's unlikely to be even worth the effort unless your whole application is made by stringing signal handlers together in combination (in which case you ought to be reading up on Qt's state machine framework, I think).